# some help with aggregate functions

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064, mysql-error-1111

I am trying to create a dynamic table using php but needed to get the query below to work normaly but am experiencing an error which I have given below the query. I need some help to fix it.

```
SELECT test_case_name AS 'Test Case', 
       AVG( no_of_satelites ) AS 'Mean Number of Satelites', 
       AVG( hdop ) AS 'Mean of HDOP', 
       AVG( longitude ) AS 'Mean of Longitude', 
       STD( AVG(  longitude ) ) AS 'StdDev of Longitude', 
       AVG( latitude ) AS 'Mean of Latitude', 
       STD( AVG( latitude ) ) AS 'StdDev of Latitude',
       ( 1.114 * pow( 10, 5 ) * STD( AVG( latitude ) ) ), 
       ( 1.114 * pow( 10, 5 ) * STD( AVG( longitude ) ) ) 
FROM  test_cases, gga_raw_data
WHERE gga_raw_data.test_case_id = test_cases.test_case_id 
GROUP BY test_case_name
```

The error says:

## 1111 - Invalid use of group function

Any suggestion or clues would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too many left parentheses. You have 2 more left parentheses than right parentheses.

This is the piece of the query that is imbalanced:

```
(( 1.114 * pow( 10, 5 ) * STD( AVG( latitude ) ) ) ,
(( 1.114 * pow( 10, 5 ) * STD( AVG( longitude ) ) )
```

Comment: Hi Ike, Just removed them and another error surfaced: #1111 - Invalid use of group function. I suspect the std cannot be used as it is in the where clause what could be right way to implment this same query?

Comment: The problem is the way you are using the `STD()` function. Where you have `STD( AVG(  longitude ) )` you probably want to do `STD(  longitude )` instead. That will give you population standard deviation of `longitude`, which is what I assume you are trying to get there.

Comment: Thanks you are right Ike. Just realised that this this morning after checking my maths to see how STD works.

Answer (score 0):

you have to have all non-aggregate columns from the SELECT clause listed in the GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT test_case_name AS 'Test Case', 
   AVG( no_of_satelites ) AS 'Mean Number of Satelites', 
   AVG( hdop ) AS 'Mean of HDOP', 
   AVG( longitude ) AS 'Mean of Longitude', 
   STD( AVG(  longitude ) ) AS 'StdDev of Longitude', 
   AVG( latitude ) AS 'Mean of Latitude', 
   STD( AVG( latitude ) ) AS 'StdDev of Latitude',
   ( 1.114 * pow( 10, 5 ) * STD( AVG( latitude ) ) ), 
   ( 1.114 * pow( 10, 5 ) * STD( AVG( longitude ) ) ) 
FROM  test_cases, gga_raw_data
WHERE gga_raw_data.test_case_id = test_cases.test_case_id 
GROUP BY test_case_name, ( 1.114 * pow( 10, 5 ) * STD( AVG( latitude ) ) ), 
   ( 1.114 * pow( 10, 5 ) * STD( AVG( longitude ) ) )
```

Comment: Thanks Leslie for pointing that out but before I do something about that, I have to correct something. Just checked my maths and realised that, it does not make sense looking for the STD() of a single value as I have done in my query i.e finding STD(AVG()). STD() is suppose to be effected on a dataset just as the AVG(). I have to put this in order.